# Background-image style with JS not working in ie9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I'm working on a site and im having some issues with my slider in IE9. What I've done is that I've made a div that gets the background image changed every few seconds depending on the img tags within.

You can see it in function here: http://diakondk.quine.pil.dk/

It works wonders in most browsers but i cant seem to figure out why its not working in IE9 or how im gonna make it work since im no JS master.

Any suggestions?

```
var slideshow = (function () {
var images = $('.img-slider-wrapper img').map(function() { 
                  return this.src; 
             }).get()
             for(i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
               $(".selector").append('<div class="dot" data-image="'+i+'" id="dot'+i+'"></div>');
             }
var index = images.length - 1;
var dot = "#dot"+index;
var timer = setTimeout(slideshow, 8000);

  $('.selector .dot').click(function() {
     index = this.dataset.image;
     $(".img-slider-wrapper").css('background-image', 'url(' + images[index] + ')');
     $(".dot.active").removeClass("active");
     dot = "#dot"+index;
     $(dot).addClass("active");
     clearTimeout(timer);
     timer = setTimeout(slideshow, 8000);
  });

  return function () {
    index = (index + 1) % images.length;
    $(".img-slider-wrapper").css('background-image', 'url(' + images[index] + ')');
    $(".dot.active").removeClass("active");
    dot = "#dot"+index;
    $(dot).addClass("active");
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(slideshow, 8000);
  }
 }());

 $(document).ready(slideshow);
```

Comment: Start by checking the error console in debug tools …

Comment: Okay, thanks for the hint :)

It turns out its the timer that is having issues .. 

timer = setTimeout(slideshow, 8000);  - Throws me an "SCRIPT87: Invalid argument."

But as far as i know that is the correct use of it? Does setTimeout not work in older versions of IE and if not is there a fallback i can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call of `setTimeout` fails in any browser, but in IE9 with an exception(what stops the further script-execution).

It's a matter of time. At the moment when you call

```
var timer = setTimeout(slideshow, 8000);
```

`slideshow` is `undefined` , and `undefined` is not a valid argument for `setTimeout`.

Wrap the call in a anonymous function:

```
var timer = setTimeout(function(){slideshow();}, 8000);
```

The anonymous function will be a valid argument for `setTimeout` and the contents of this function will be evaluated after 8sec(when `slideshow` is defined and a function)

Comment: Thanks that worked wonders, actually tried this solution but forgot to add the () after slideshow after reading about it and thought my example was an exception, thanks for making me retry it! :)